# What does getnewaddress return

Tags: json-rpc

The address generated by `getnewaddress` RPC is associated to a wallet that the user possesses or is it a random address not necessarily belonging to user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns an address you can use, not merely some useless random number.

It generates a new pair of public and private keys, stores those keys in your wallet and generates the address from the public key.